# Why $S^{\infty}$ quotient by the action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is $\mathbb{R}P^{\infty}$

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is known that $\displaystyle S^{\infty}=\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\cup}}S^n$. Considering the action of $\mathbb{Z}_2$, can anyone explain me **in a detailed way** why $S^{\infty}/\mathbb{Z}_2\cong\mathbb{R}P^{\infty}$ where $\mathbb{R}P^{\infty}=\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty}{\cup}}\mathbb{R}P^n$?

Comment: Do you know how $S^n/\mathbb{Z}_2 \cong \mathbb{RP}^n$ ?

Comment: Yes, but it would be great to add in the answer too to make it better explained.

Comment: Perhaps you should provide more context, tell us what you already know and what level your knowledge is already at. You are kind of just saying "explain this to me", which isn't exactly a great question and is actually quite difficult to respond to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $i_n:S^n\rightarrow S^{n+1}$ induced by $f^n:R^n\rightarrow R^{n+1}$ defined by $f_n(x_1,..,x_n)=(x_1,..,x_n,0)$, you can write $S^{\infty}=lim(i_n)$. Remark that $RP^n$ is the quotient of $S^n$ by the antipodal $j_n$ which commutes with $i_n$, thus $RP^{\infty}=lim_nRP^n=lim_nS^n/Z_2$ (the action is induced by $j_n$) $=(lim_nS^n)/Z_2=S^{\infty}/Z_2$ where the action in the two last quotients is induced by $j=lim j_n$.